# Extension method for dictionary with value implementing interface

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, extension-methods

I'm trying to implement an extension method for all dictionaries whose value is of a type that implement a certain interface. 
In this case I would like to have a ToListSortedByValue() method that returns

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, IComparable>>
```

for any dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<string, IComparable>
```

that would be cool because it would allow me to use dictionaries instead of lists, but to be able to have them sorted when needed (for example when printing in files or at console).

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work, any idea why?

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, IComparable>> ToListSortedByValue(this Dictionary<string, IComparable> Dic)
{
    return Dic.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

EDIT:
it's solved already, but for completeness sake this is the problem I got:
when trying to use the method I got the an error as if such method didn't exist. If instead of IComparable I use an actual comparable type, let's say int or a class implementing IComparable, than it would work.

Comment: And why doesn't it work?

Comment: Why not make it generic on the value type with a constraint that it's `IComparable`?

Comment: Because when trying to use the method I get the an error if such method didn't exist. If instead of IComparable I use an actual comparable type, let's say int or a class implementing IComparable, than it would work.

Comment: juharr that sounds like what I need, could you post some example code? That would be of massive help!

Comment: @ManuelVenè You should include that information about the error in the question.

Comment: Note that this *would* work if you actually had a `Dictionary<string, IComparable>`. That's why it's important to provide a [mcve] so we can see it not working for ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to make the method generic on the value type and then constrain that type to be `IComparable<T>`.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> ToListSortedByValue<T>(
    this Dictionary<string, T> Dic) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return Dic.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

This has the added bonus of returning the values as there passed in type.  You might even want to make the key type generic too so it's not limited to just `string`

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ToListSortedByValue<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dic) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
{
    return Dic.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That should be `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah that's better.

Comment: Absolutely awasome!! whit IComparable<T> it works just fine. The extra generalization bit on the key made it even greater. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your method generic, so that it extends your actual type instead of just `IComparable`:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> ToListSortedByValue<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> Dic) where T : IComparable<T>
```